# Separar dados por valores na linha?

Tags: r, data, data.frame, split

Nas linhas do meu dataframe eu possuo um identificador com letras para cada conjunto de observação. Algumas das observações possuem mais de uma letra, no caso essas observações são ações em conjunto das respectivas letras "solteiras".

ex:

- `a` = um conjunto de ação,
- `b` = outro conjunto,
- `ab` = valor de a+b associado.

Gostaria de separar meus dados em [r](/questions/tagged/r), a partir das letras associadas, obtendo um novo conjunto de dados apenas com os dados referentes aos valores associados e os respectivos solteiros.

ex:

- `a`, `b`, `ab`.

Coloquei uma imagem para exemplificar melhor e também possuo um código para o exemplo dos dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para os dados:

```
comprar = c(rep("a",times = 4), rep("b",times = 4), rep("c",times = 4), rep("ab",times = 4), rep("ac",times = 4), rep("bc",times = 4))

custo = c(12,14,16,18,22,24,26,28,17,19,21,23,34,36,38,42,44,46,48,52,62,64,66,68)

data = cbind(comprar, custo)
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar `split`:

```
data = data.frame(comprar=comprar, custo=custo)
Y = split(data, data$comprar)
```

Para cada nível diferente de `comprar` vc vai ter um `data.frame` dentro de uma lista:

```
$a
  comprar custo
1       a    12
2       a    14
3       a    16
4       a    18

$ab
   comprar custo
13      ab    34
14      ab    36
15      ab    38
16      ab    42

$ac
   comprar custo
17      ac    44
18      ac    46
19      ac    48
20      ac    52
```

Se você quiser que cada objeto dessa lista esteja em um `data.frame` diretamente, você pode fazer:

```
list2env(Y, envir = .GlobalEnv)
a
ab
```

E os nomes únicos da variável `comprar` serão os nomes dos `data.frames` na sua sessão

Answer (score 2):

Como [respondido por @guilherme-parreira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496364/117168) usar `split` é a melhor maneira para separar os dados por uma variável:

```
dados <- data.frame(
  comprar = c(rep("a",times = 4), rep("b",times = 4), rep("c",times = 4), rep("ab",times = 4), rep("ac",times = 4), rep("bc",times = 4)),
  custo = c(12,14,16,18,22,24,26,28,17,19,21,23,34,36,38,42,44,46,48,52,62,64,66,68)
)

dados.lista <- split(dados, dados$comprar)
```

Para selecionar os grupos e as associações, pode usar uma pequena função usando `strsplit`:

```
selGrp <- function(grp) c(strsplit(grp, "")[[1]], grp)

selGrp("abc")
#> [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "abc"

dados.lista[selGrp("ab")]
#> $a
#>   comprar custo
#> 1       a    12
#> 2       a    14
#> 3       a    16
#> 4       a    18
#>
#> $b
#>   comprar custo
#> 5       b    22
#> 6       b    24
#> 7       b    26
#> 8       b    28
#>
#> $ab
#>    comprar custo
#> 13      ab    34
#> 14      ab    36
#> 15      ab    38
#> 16      ab    42
```

Para fazer isso para todas as associações:

```
# Níveis da variável comprar:
lv.comprar <- levels(dados$comprar)
# ou, se a variável comprar não for do tipo fator:
lv.comprar <- as.character(unique(dados$comprar))

# Encontra as associações (i.e., os valores que tem mais de um caracter):
assocs <- lv.comprar[nchar(lv.comprar) > 1]

# Cria uma lista nomeada em que cada elemento é uma lista com os data.frames selecionados de cada associação:
dados.spl <- setNames(lapply(assocs, function(x) dados.lista[selGrp(x)]), assocs)

str(dados.spl, max.level = 2)
#> List of 3
#>  $ ab:List of 3
#>   ..$ a :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ b :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ab:'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ ac:List of 3
#>   ..$ a :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ c :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ac:'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ bc:List of 3
#>   ..$ b :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ c :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ bc:'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:

dados.spl$ac
#> $a
#>   comprar custo
#> 1       a    12
#> 2       a    14
#> 3       a    16
#> 4       a    18
#>
#> $c
#>    comprar custo
#> 9        c    17
#> 10       c    19
#> 11       c    21
#> 12       c    23
#>
#> $ac
#>    comprar custo
#> 17      ac    44
#> 18      ac    46
#> 19      ac    48
#> 20      ac    52
```

Manter como lista é o mais versátil. Se quiser converter os elementos para data.frame:

```
# Formato comprido
dados.spl.comp <- lapply(dados.spl, data.frame)

dados.spl.comp$ac
#>   a.comprar a.custo c.comprar c.custo ac.comprar ac.custo
#> 1         a      12         c      17         ac       44
#> 2         a      14         c      19         ac       46
#> 3         a      16         c      21         ac       48
#> 4         a      18         c      23         ac       52

# Formato longo
dados.spl.long <- lapply(dados.spl, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))

dados.spl.long$ac
#>       comprar custo
#> a.1         a    12
#> a.2         a    14
#> a.3         a    16
#> a.4         a    18
#> c.9         c    17
#> c.10        c    19
#> c.11        c    21
#> c.12        c    23
#> ac.17      ac    44
#> ac.18      ac    46
#> ac.19      ac    48
#> ac.20      ac    52
```

Ou, em uma linha:

```
setNames(lapply(assocs, function(x) do.call(rbind, dados.lista[selGrp(x)])), assocs)

setNames(lapply(assocs, function(x) data.frame(dados.lista[selGrp(x)])), assocs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Entendo que o objetivo é obter os conjuntos finais já separados, e que o processo possa ser o mais automático.

Se tivéssemos as listas com os valores do atributo "compra" de cada subconjunto, bastaria fazer um filter para obter a resposta. Isto é o que está implementado na função "retriev_sub_df abaixo".

Me parece que o principal desafio é justamente obter os diferentes conjuntos <a, b, ab> , <a, c, ac>, etc... Ou ainda implementar isto de tal forma que suporte outras combinações além as dos dados de exemplo.

Porém, <a, b, ab> possui informações que já estão dentro de "ab". Ou seja, se for possível obter a lista de tuplas, os elementos individuais podem ser recuperados. Isto é o que faz a funçáo "retrieve_tokens" abaixo.

O uso de listas e da função map garante uma solução automática elegante.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(comprar = comprar,
             custo = custo)

retrive_tokens <- function() {
  tokens <- tibble(df %>% distinct(comprar))
  tokens <- tokens %>% 
    mutate(
      len = str_length(comprar)
    ) 
  max_tl = max(token$len)
  tokens <- tokens %>% 
    filter(len == max_tl)
  tokens$comprar
}

retrieve_sub_df <- function(token) {
  criteria = unlist(list(token, str_split(token, "")))
  sub_df <- df %>% 
    filter(
      comprar %in% criteria
    )
}

tokens = retrive_tokens()
result <- map(tokens, ~retrieve_sub_df(.x))

result[[1]]
result[[2]]
result[[3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Atualização em 11/03/2021**

Devido à pontuação negativa recebida em minha resposta, estou atualizando este post com uma informação que talvez não seja de conhecimento de todos.

> É possível rodar código Python dentro de um script [r](/questions/tagged/r) utilizando o [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)

Retirado direto do site (em inglês)

> The reticulate package provides a comprehensive set of tools for interoperability between Python and R. The package includes facilities for:
>
> - Calling Python from R in a variety of ways including R Markdown, sourcing Python scripts, importing Python modules, and using Python interactively within an R session.
> - Translation between R and Python objects (for example, between R and Pandas data frames, or between R matrices and NumPy arrays).
> - Flexible binding to different versions of Python including virtual environments and Conda environments.

Em resumo do descrito acima, é possível chamar um script Python de dentro do R, traduzir de objetos R para objetos Python (ex.: R e Pandas) e usar ambientes virtuais do Python.

Acredito que a solução abaixo atenderá ao solicitado pelo autor da pergunta.

**Fim da atualização**

Solução baseada em Python

```
import pandas as pd

comprar = ["a"]*4 + ["b"]*4 + ["c"]*4 + ["ab"]*4 + ["ac"]*4 + ["bc"]*4
custo = [12,14,16,18,22,24,26,28,17,19,21,23,34,36,38,42,44,46,48,52,62,64,66,68]

df = pd.DataFrame({"comprar": comprar, "custo": custo})

grupos = df.groupby(["comprar"])

for grupo in grupos:
    print(f"Chave = {grupo[0]}")
    print(f"Grupo = \n{grupo[1]}")
    print(80*"-")
```

A saída será

```
Chave = a
Grupo =
   index comprar  custo
0      0       a     12
1      1       a     14
2      2       a     16
3      3       a     18
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chave = ab
Grupo =
   index comprar  custo
0     12      ab     34
1     13      ab     36
2     14      ab     38
3     15      ab     42
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chave = ac
Grupo =
   index comprar  custo
0     16      ac     44
1     17      ac     46
2     18      ac     48
3     19      ac     52
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chave = b
Grupo =
   index comprar  custo
0      4       b     22
1      5       b     24
2      6       b     26
3      7       b     28
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chave = bc
Grupo =
   index comprar  custo
0     20      bc     62
1     21      bc     64
2     22      bc     66
3     23      bc     68
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Atualização em 11/03/2021**

Transforme os grupos em um dicionário de dataframes, onde a chave é o valor agrupado e o valor é o resultado agrupado

```
d = dict(tuple(grupos))

d["a"]
  comprar  custo
0       a     12
1       a     14
2       a     16
3       a     18


d["ac"]
   comprar  custo
16      ac     44
17      ac     46
18      ac     48
19      ac     52
```

**Fim da atualização**